# clearcontent certain cells /columns on row contains certain tex

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i found this great formula that works so great on my need, sorry i forgot it original source

The Original Code is move the entire Row if it found "X" on Columns 21 and copy  the entire row to sheet with same name as col 22 and delete the Entire row

1st Question,

instead the delete entire row, i need it only to clear certains Columns, for example it only clear content Columns 3, 4, 10 and 12 only << Solved thanks to **idfurw**

2nd Question,
how to lock this script to only a certain sheet?

here the new script base on update from **idfurw**

Main Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
// see Sheet event objects docs
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
var ss = e.source;
var s = e.range.getSheet();
if (s.getName() == 'Form');
var r = e.range;

// to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
var actionCol = 21;
var nameCol = 22;
// Get the row and column of the active cell.
var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
// Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
// -1 to drop our action/status column
var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;
// if our action/status col is changed to ok do stuff
if (e.value == "XX" && colIndex == actionCol) {
// get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority column
var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
// if the sheet exists do more stuff
if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
// set our target sheet and target range
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
// get our source range/row
var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
// new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
// ..but we can still delete the row after
const cols = [6, 7, 8, 12,14,16,17,19,20,21];
for (const col of cols) {
  s.getRange(rowIndex, col).clearContent();
}

// or you might want to keep but note move e.g. r.setValue("moved");
}
}
}
```

Time Stamp Script

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+7";
  var time_format = "dd-MM-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Pasien";
  var timeStampColName = "Tgl Keluar";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Form'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
 
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) 
  
  { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
  
  if (sheet.getRange(index, updateCol).isBlank()) {
  sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1).clearContent();
}
else 
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, time_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove this line to disable deleting row:**

```js
s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
```

**Replace with the following to clear content of specified cols:**

```js
const cols = [3, 4, 10, 12];
for (const col of cols) {
  s.getRange(rowIndex, col).clearContent();
}
```

---

**To limit the function to a particular sheet:**

```js
var s = e.range.getSheet();
/* add it after the above line */
if (s.getName() !== 'Name of sheet') { return; }
```

Comment: @idkfurw Thankyou for response, Would you help me to for the 2nd question, how to lock this script to only a certain sheet?

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: it doesnt work, does it interfere with timestamp script. Would you check it out

Comment: Then you should remove `return` (let it blank), and wrap the remaining part before `else` (timestamp part) with an `else`

Comment: already  remove ```return;``` and(let it blank),  I lost in "and wrap the remaining part before ```else``` (timestamp part) with an ```else```"

Comment: Let,s do it the opposite way `if (s.getName() == 'Name of sheet') {` if (dateCol > -1 ... , `}` else ...

Comment: ``` if (s.getName() == 'Name of sheet') ``` Previously ``` if (s.getName() !== 'Name of sheet') ``` Still not working.  if i add  ``` { ``` if (dateCol > -1 ... , ``` }```  else. Time Stamp script doesnt work.

Comment: Yes i have 2 scripts on 2 different files.  You helped me with those two scripts. They works fine if only one of them. When i put each script on each files. ````Main Script```` wont work. im very noob at this thing, thankyou for your help.  Should I accept this Question and open another one?

Comment: Sorry, I could answer you here. When there are multiple functions with the same name. Only the last once would work. You should better combine them into one (but may be two different nested functions inside it) since they are both trigger upon edit.

Comment: ahh thats the answer, you are awsome. maybe it gonna take me a week to learn the whole process. Would you help me combine them on another Question